# Method call in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I need to retrieve documents which comply to certain criteria.

The below query throws a `System.NotSupportedException`.

```
var documents = await _context.Documents.Where(d => d.CreatedDate > 
                            filter.From && d.CreatedDate < filter.To && 
                            HighestProbabilityCategories(d).Any(x => 
                            Ids.Any(y => y == x.CategoryId)))
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedDate)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Basically, every document has a number of categories each with an id(`Guid`) and a probability(`float`). I need to retrieve the documents whose categories' ids are among those in `Ids`, such that the probability of each of those categories is the highest among all the categories for that specific document. I hope it's clear.

```
private IEnumerable<Category> HighestProbabilityCategories(Documents doc)
{
    var hightest = doc.Category.Max(p => p.Probability);
    return doc.Category.Where(c => c.Probability == hightest);
}
```

I realize that on the database side, the method call wouldn't make any sense.
The only other way i could think of is to filter the documents by dates first, and then for each of those documents, add the categories with the highest probability to a dictionary `<document, List<Category>`, and simply retrieve that list during the query using the document as a key. However, i wasn't sure how efficient that would be or if there would be a better way.

Comment: "However, i wasn't sure how efficient that would be" Why ask us? How sould we know? Just try it out and see if it fits your requirements. Only **if** you encounter performance-problems you may consider to optimize your code, but even than only on basis of an exact measurement, e.g. using a profiler.

Comment: Try moving the "any" clause outside (after) the "where"

Comment: I need to see the class with the property Ids.  The object is not enumerable.

Comment: Ids is simply `List<Guid> Ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guid>>(filter.Ids);` and `filter.Ids` is a string.

Comment: This looks like an Entity Framework query.  You can't use "code based" functions inside there, since EF doesn't know how to translate the code in to SQL.

Comment: You could look into using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit).